# Meteor: Publish function requires a page refresh after user logs in

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a meteor app and I'm calling all the publish functions at once in the iron router configuration like below. I only want to return the subscriptions once the user is logged in, so I check Meteor.userId():

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundTemplate: '404',
  waitOn: function () {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
      return [Meteor.subscribe('users'),
          Meteor.subscribe('company'),
          Meteor.subscribe('projects'),
          Meteor.subscribe('columns'),
          Meteor.subscribe('cards'),
          Meteor.subscribe('contents'),
          Meteor.subscribe('labels'),
          Meteor.subscribe('notifications')];
    }
  }
});
```

The publish functions have all the same structure, dependent on user.companyId, like this:

```
Meteor.publish('cards', function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    const user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.userId, companyId: { $exists: true } });

    if (user) {
        return Cards.find({ companyId: user.companyId });
    }
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

My problem is, when the user registers, the account is created and the companyId is saved to the user, but when they now login, the only way for the data to show up is to refresh the browser. I want it to be reactive.

Comment: You can use publish-composite to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [meteor guide](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#publishing-relations):

> On the client, if anything in a reactive function changes, the whole
>   function will re-run, and the results are fairly intuitive.
>
> On the server however, the reactivity is limited to the behavior of
>   the cursors you return from your publish functions. You’ll see any
>   changes to the data that matches their queries, but **their queries
>   will never change**.

You can indeed use [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) as suggested, but for your simple case I think [reactive-publish](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish) would be much easier to get up and running.

Install the package, and just wrap your publication in a `this.autorun`:

```
Meteor.publish('cards', function () {
  this.autorun( function() {
    if (this.userId) {
      const user = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.userId, companyId: { $exists: true } });

      if (user) {
          return Cards.find({ companyId: user.companyId });
      }
    } else {
      this.ready();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Also I think you want to `return` in your `else` statement